# What are the problems humans will face after migration to Mars

Tags: mars, future-missions

This was the question I was asked to check the research ability. Forgive me because I have just started this topic. What do you think could be the best answer?

**Background**

Once upon a time in
the year 2120...
Humans finally met extraterrestrial civilizations. Spaceships are now able to travel to
galaxies far away. Isaac Asimov can finally be proud of us.

It turned out that the Martian B2B market looks pretty attractive.
Martian entrepreneurs are hard workers. SMEs on Mars produce goods and provide services.
But… they need liquidity, insurance, and collections.
Same problems as on Earth.

**Question**

*Think about problems our Martian business may face in 2120*: e.g. Oxygen supply, Marketing,
Vegetables for the Team, Accounting, etc. and potential solutions to each of them.

**My Answer**

1. **Oxygen** -
   The atmosphere of Mars is the layer of gas surrounding Mars. It is primarily composed of carbon dioxide (95.32%), molecular nitrogen (2.6%) and argon (1.9%). It also contains trace levels of water vapor, oxygen(0.1%), carbon monoxide, hydrogen, and other noble gases.  Human breathe air that is 21 percent oxygen, and we require oxygen to live.

*Solution* :
- we are fairly successful to convert carbon dioxide to Oxygen with diff experiments, there will be companies on mars that provide devices to which does this. However, there will be scientists to find out solutions about pure human-friendly air and there will be shark tanks who support them.

2. **transport** :

*Solution*

As we know The SpaceX Starship is planned to be a long-duration cargo- and passenger-carrying spacecraft launched as the second stage of a reusable launch vehicle. similarly, by 2120 there will be lots of other companies who would have done mastering in Mars travel. and this will be the top 10 business related to Mars.

Comment: Welcome to space stack exchange. I suggest you read the help center, especially What Types of Questions should I avoid asking? https://space.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask  Note "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."  If you can [edit] your question to focus on a single, answerable, non-opinion based query, it could be a good fit for this site.

Comment: Thanks, @OrganicMarble for the tip, let me edit the question with possible answerable.

Comment: Some things to consider about Mars. The atmosphere is very thin & mostly contains CO2. Temperatures on Mars are cold. Water, oxygen & energy will be required to sustain life. There is evidence of perchlorates in soils on Mars. Perchlorates are toxic, which presents problems for growing plants. Cosmic radiation on the surface of Mars is high due to the thinness of the atmosphere & the lack of a magnetic field.

Comment: @BhavinRana as a hint, the only place that a question mark appears in your question is "What do you think could be the best answer?" and of course "what do you think" is problematic for Stack Exchange, and "the best answer" will be defined by community votes and your choice of acceptance. *Welcome to Space!*